# FInding ID of checked Radio Button, How to strip string form ID

Tags: android

In my application,  the user selects a radio button indicating how many players he has wanting to play a sport o this choosing. The number is then sent to another activity to be displayed. And if possible, how can i take the id of the radio button and strip the "radio" part, leaving just the integer 4-10?

```
package teamBuilder;

import com.jonahwitcig.team.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;


public class CorrectedActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    TextView player1, team1;
    Button next;
    RadioGroup RBGroup;
    RadioButton RB4, RB5, RB6, RB7, RB8, RB9, RB10;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.players);

        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        //the name of a textView i will be displaying a number in
        team1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team1);
        RB4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio4);
        RB5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio5);
        RB6 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio6);
        RB7 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio7);
        RB8 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio8);
        RB9 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio9);
        RB10 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio10);
        //names of my radio buttons
        RBGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RBGroup);



        RBGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup RBGroup, int checkedId) {

                team1.setText(checkedId);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Does `team1.setText(checkedId)` display a long number (its unique identifier)?

Comment: no it just displays an integer

Comment: Ok, what is the text displayed with your radio buttons? Or better yet would you add your XML layout?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not recommended (reverse look-up is quite slow if done in a large batch, but will be unnoticeable if done rarely), here is the correct solution (Keep in mind that you need to include your own error checking/handling for malformed identifier strings):

```
String resName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(checkedId);
String number = resName.substring(5);
int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
```